# Swift How to upload images into firebase with different file names?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to IOS please consider. My problem is that whenever I upload images, it's just replacing existing  images.

Now I want to upload image with unique file name. I am taking image from camera.

```
func uploadtofirebase(){

        let imagepath = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.imagebutton.image!)
        if imagepath == nil {
            return
        }
        var strURL = "imagePickerController.png"

       let storage = Storage.storage()
       let storageRef = storage.reference().child("IosImages/").child(strURL)
          print("calling here successfully ")
        storageRef.putData(imagepath!, metadata:nil,completion:
            {(metadata,error) in storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in

                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString{
                    strURL = urlText
                    print("///////////tttttttt//////// \(strURL)   ////////")
                    //completion(strURL)
                    print("passed activity")
                    self.startReceivingLocationChanges()
                }
            })
        })
}
```

Note: `.child(strURL)` I think `strURL` I have to make it dynamic. I have done in android, but I am not able do iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create image name dynamically. Something like this '20181010045120.png'. You can generate it using function something like this

```
 func generateImageName() -> String {
    let date = Date()
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmSS"
    let result = formatter.string(from: date)
    return "\(result).png"
 }
```

Just call this function and you will get new image name everytime. This also usefull as it contain Date time on which it generated.